# checking version of C library (dynamic loading)

Tags: c, linux, unix, gcc, dynamic-linking

I have a program that requires specific versions of libraries (libgstreamer is an example), and therefore an older version will not work. Due to lazy linking it's possible that my program will link to gstreamer version 10.23 which is missing some of the symbols present in 10.25 that I use. My question is, how can I check which version of a library is installed without using the package manager to do so. Is it possible to load a library from a C program an check its version number using dlopen() perhaps?

Edit: I'm working on a Linux system

Edit 2: Perhaps I can use readelf -V ?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably you could link against libgstreamer.so.X.XX instead of libgstreamer.so. Also look at: http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO.html#VERSION-SCRIPTS

Comment: On Windows, you would just specify the minimum acceptable version number of the dependent assembly in your application manifest, and the OS would take care of it. Sadly, posix devs still think the linking against versioned softlinks system is superior, and windows dev's don't know how to create assemblies for shared components.

Comment: @RedX: why not put that in an answer?

Comment: @RedX: Yes, that should work. However, this would lock the program to *exactly* one version, while usually only a certain *minimum* version is required.

Comment: In my situation, I need to use a workaround if the library is older than a certain version, but I don't want to prevent using the app with older versions, so doing it through dependencies isn't a solution.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, how can I check which
>   version of a library is installed
>   without using the package manager to
>   do so.

First, please note that the usual and accepted mechanism to handle this on Linux is precisely to let the package manager check it - that's one of the main reasons they were invented.

The other common option is to check in your `configure` script or `Makefile` when building from source.

If you want to supply precompiled binaries, but not use a package manager, I believe the best mechanism is to check if the library has some internal mechanism to retrieve its version at runtime. This is unfortunately specific for each library you link against.

GStreamer fortunately has this:

```
void gst_version(guint *major, guint *minor, guint *micro, guint *nano);
Gets the version number of the GStreamer library.
```

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gstreamer-GstVersion.html

You could just call this function on startup, and bail out if the version is not OK.

Still, I'd urge you to reconsider not using a package manager. It really is the most painless mechanism to handle this, and also allows easy installation for users (if you provide a repository).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At the moment I do use the package manager, the issue with this is that its becoming a problem to maintain various scripts for different distributions. Even worse, it does not work at all with systems that use package manager for which we have not provided a script (say arch linux or slackware).

Comment: @lordsandwich: Ah, I see. Well, you could always limit your support to some popular distros (and their derivatives), and tell others to do the stuff by hand. People who use slackware should be able to check .so versions themselves :-).

Answer (score 2):

Sure, use the dlopen and dlsym functions to load the library and test for the existence of the symbols you are dependent on. See the man page for details and a code example: http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen

Comment: I did think of that, but the list of symbols is very long (as there a lot of libraries that  I need to check for). Given that I know which version contains all the symbols required I would prefer to use a solution that checked for the versio number. Is there no way of using dlsym() for versio nchecking? I couldn't find anything about that on the man page.

Comment: From the man page I referenced above:
'The function dlvsym() does the same as dlsym() but takes a version string as an additional argument.'

Answer (score 0):

Try using **ltrace** or **strace**

```
ltrace -f -e dlopen ./<theapp>
strace ./<theapp> 2>&1| grep 'dlopen.*'
```

PS! Haven't tested myself

Comment: the dlopen call displayed does not show what version of library is being dynamically loaded.

Comment: Also, I don't think this will help, as the question was about doing this from inside the program (though you could in principle run the commands from the program).

Comment: hmm, http://forums.purebasic.com/english/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=45962 suggests that it does, what does it output in your case? If it just says libgstreamer.so you need to check what libgstreamer.so.X.XX file it is a link to.

Comment: it does say libgstreamer.so,0.10. That means it excludes the last (and important version number, I need libgstreamar 0.10.25 or above.